# Where is req.user coming from in this node and express lines of codes

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning node.js and express.js and I was watching a tutorial video and coding along.

Here, the tutor wrote a code for user to delete their own post:

```
//Delete post
const deletePost = async (req, res)=>{
const {user: {userId}} = req
console.log(req)
 try{
    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
    const user = await User.findById(userId)
    
     if(post.username == req.body.username ){
        try{
            await Post.findByIdAndDelete(post._id);                      
                res.status(200).json("Post has been deleted")
        }catch(err){
            res.status(401).json(err)
            }
     } else{
         res.status(401).json("you can only delete your posts")

     } 
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err)
}

}
```

Out of curiosity, I console.log(req.user) and I saw the data that contained the user details. My question is where is the object name 'user' coming from? Was this created by default or must have been created in the code somewhere? I mean the name. Can it be named req.owner, or req.account, etc. Or it must be req.user and came by default?

I also console.log(req), I saw giant objects for sure and among them is the user object. Is it there by default?

Comment: It's probably being added to the request object by some _middleware_, but without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: This means that it was never there by default, right? Somehow, must have been added by some codes?

Comment: Correct, Express itself has no idea who or what you consider the user to be.

Comment: Okay, I actually knew that the details inside the 'user' were input made by the user.. My main question is the name 'user'. I want to know if that name came by default like req.body, req.query, req.params, etc.

Comment: You can see what the default properties of a request are in the API docs: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.

Comment: I have seen it. The object name 'user' is not a default property. It was added as a parameter in one of the middlewares. Precisely, the jwt verification middleware.

Comment: Assuming you mean [`express-jwt`](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt#retrieving-the-decoded-payload), that defaults to the `user` property but can be configured to put it elsewhere.